# Passing a value from jquery to php to another view

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am getting the value of a checkbox using jquery. How can I pass that value in another view? I want to use it to access data from the DB. This is how far I've got.

## Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function(){
            $('#btnClick').click(function(){
                var val = [];
                $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
                val[i] = $(this).val();
                });
            });
        });
//SOME CODE
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'submission-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('submission/create'),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
    )); 
//SOME CODE
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Next', array('id'=>'btnClick','name'=>'btnClick',)); ?>
```

Comment: If you want to use that value on the server, you'll need to use AJAX

Comment: send ajax call to some action and do it

Comment: He can do it with a common request as well and reload the page. But I do not understand his main goal.

Comment: If you are using form and submit then check box values will be post to next page. you can get it using $_POST easily..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){
        $('#btnClick').click(function(){
            var val = [];
            $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
            val[i] = $(this).val();
             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "some.php",
               data: { Value: val[i] }
                   })
               .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                 });
            });
        });
    });
//SOME CODE
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'submission-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('submission/create'),
    'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'),
)); 
//SOME CODE
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Next', array('id'=>'btnClick','name'=>'btnClick',)); ?>
```

**And In Some.php**
Get that value in variable like

```
<?php $Selected_Value = $_POST['Value']; ?>
```

And Perform any database query here.

Comment: I copied that code and changed some.php to create.php(which is the view I am redirrecting to) but I get the error `Undefined index: Value` when I try to access the variable.

Comment: what is the name of your checkbox button

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="journal_id" value="'.$value->object_id.'">

Comment: Now on create.php use $_POST['journal_id']